# C# foreach not returning unique values in list comparison

Tags: c#, foreach

I have 2 lists of objects to compare form a matching field and create a new list. The new list should contain objects from List2 and remove objects found in list1.

The code below is not returning unique objects but looping through 6 times - the number of objects in List1 adding each to the list.

```cs
List<ViewportWrapper> vpList = new(); // List1 - has count of 6
List<ViewWrapper> vList = new(); // List2 - has count of 25
List<ViewWrapper> vNoSheet = new(); // New list - has count of 120 - should be 19

foreach (var vpId in colViewports)
{
    var tempvpid = vpId.ViewportViewId;
    vpList.Add(vpId);
    foreach (var v in colViews)
    {
        var tempv = v.ViewId;
        if (v.ViewIsTemplate == false)
        {
            vList.Add(v);
        }
        if (tempv != tempvpid && v.ViewIsTemplate == false)
        {
            vNoSheet.Add(v);
        }
    }
}
```

the complete class is

```
public ObservableCollection<ViewWrapper> GetViews()
    {
        var colViewports = new FilteredElementCollector(Doc)
            .OfClass(typeof(Viewport))
            .ToElements()
            .Select(x => new ViewportWrapper((Viewport)x));

        var colViews = new FilteredElementCollector(Doc)
            .OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Views)
            .WhereElementIsNotElementType()
            .ToElements()
            .Select(x => new ViewWrapper((View)x));

        List<ViewportWrapper> vpList = new();
        List<ViewWrapper> vList = new();
        List<ViewWrapper> vNoSheet = vList.Distinct().ToList();

        foreach (var vpId in colViewports)
        {
            var tempvpid = vpId.ViewportViewId;
            vpList.Add(vpId);
            foreach (var v in colViews)
            {
                var tempv = v.ViewId;
                if (v.ViewIsTemplate == false)
                {
                    vList.Add(v);
                }
                if (tempv != tempvpid && v.ViewIsTemplate == false)
                {
                    vNoSheet.Add(v);
                }
            }
        }

        return new ObservableCollection<ViewWrapper>(vNoSheet);
```

how to return a list of unique objects?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you mean that you want the new list to only contain elements that exclusively exist in List2 (and thus cannot be found in List1)?

Comment: yes  - the new list should be elements left after removing List1 elements from List2 elements. List2 original contains all elements including List1. How to remove List1 elements from List2.

Comment: Do you have the ViewWrapper elements in colViews ordered? Did you try with _foreach (var v in colViews.OrderBy(x => x.ViewId))_ If there is no order the results of the second if are impredictable

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], with definition of your classes, some sample data and the expected output

Comment: `Enumerable.Except` Method. Definition: The set difference of two sets is defined as the members of the first set that don't appear in the second set.

This method returns those elements in first that don't appear in second. It doesn't return those elements in second that don't appear in first. Only unique elements are returned.

Comment: @T.S. not sure that will work since the lists are composed from items of different classes

Comment: @BojanB custom comparer can be added... unless I am missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code example I would use something like this:

```
foreach(var vpId in colViewports)
{
     vpList.Add(vpId);
}

foreach (var v in colViews)
{
    if(v.ViewIsTemplate)
        continue;
    vList.Add(v);
    var foundInListOne = colViewports.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ViewportViewId == v.ViewId); 
    if (foundInListOne == null)
        vNoSheet.Add(v); 
}
```

You only add the item to the new list if the `ViewIsTemplate` property is false, so there is no need for 2 ifs, just skip to the next item if it is true. Otherwise add the item to the vList and then check if any first list item with the `ViewportViewId` that equals the `ViewId` of the current second list item exists, if not then add it to the thrid list.

I hope this helps, your question is a bit confusing since you use different names for lists one and two in the code and in the definition.

In your example the items are filtered because due to the nested iteration, you should have 150 (6 * 25) items. But due to the nested iteration all other items except the matches get added.